# How to check /root/cron.php/ is working or not

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, fedex

I have create fedex module that complate the order status based on product delivery status and setup with **/root/cron.php/**.

but i don't know to check cron schedules are working or not. Any manual trick to check the cron are working or not?

Comment: Did you get what you want?

Comment: no. i have not got any solution for this. :(

Comment: Did you tried putting `mage::log()` In cron.php file?. Is there any log generating?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to **cron.sh** after the INSTALLDIR variable is set:

```
# absolute path to magento installation
INSTALLDIR=`echo $0 | sed 's/cron\.sh//g'`
date >> "$0".log
whoami  >> "$0".log
```

And this to **cron.php** after the **dispatchEvent** call:

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('default');
$log = fopen(__FILE__.'.log', 'a');
fwrite($log, date("Y-m-d H:i:s").PHP_EOL);
fclose($log);
```

After 6 minutes you should see both these files in Magento's directory if cron is running.

```
./cron.php.log
./cron.sh.log
```

If you have tried everything and still cant get cron to work, perhaps this unsupported workaround might help. Adding the following to the top of index.php will cause cron to run in the background whenever someone accesses your website.

```
<?php
$pathToCron = dirname(__FILE__)."/cron.sh";
exec( "sh $pathToCron > /dev/null &" );
```

Another workaround

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/wget http://your_webpage.com/cron.php
```

You can check more information [here](http://help.sweettoothrewards.com/article/395-setting-up-cron-jobs-in-magento)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

1. Straight forward way would be to configure

   ```
    */5 * * * * /usr/bin/bash /path_to/cron.php
   ```

   in cron tab.
2. Backup and Truncate cron_schedule table.
3. Wait for cron run. Cron will insert the data.
4. You can also check by hitting cron.php from the URL.

*Note : I would not recommend configuring cron with wget.*